# Unable to login into IE when privacy option is set to medium and above.

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session

I have done a login form where variables are passed through session. It works fine in Mozilla but in case of Internet Explorer (IE) when the privacy option is set to medium and above  the login fails to work.

I have maintained a session for normal users by passing their username and admin users by passing their usertype. If nobody logs in then they can see the webpage without the facilities that are provided for logged in users.

So I am stuck in a situation where I have to maintain a session variable in order to differentiate users, without which I am unable to redirect.

Now in case of IE users who have enabled medium or above privacy, session variables cannot be passed due to which they will not be able to login, I cannot even redirect them to a different page which will ask them to lower their privacy policy in order for them to login, cause I'm my code if session is not maintained then a normal page has to be shown.

Is there any method in PHP with which we can ask the user to lower their privacy option in Internet Explorer?

Comment: I think it's much related to PHP and it's sessions.
But might be browse is not sending you GET or POST method correctly.
or don't have cookies enabled. and so no..

Comment: You can check browser type if ie and not logged in then ask user to lower their privacy option

Comment: @mufaddal: can you tell me how to do that in Php :)

Comment: you can use javascript to detect brwoser something like "window.navigator.userAgent"

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the users just going to the database every time you need them. Just keep a sesion variable with the sesion id and assign it to the user in the database. This way you don't have to maintain nor pass the user trough every website section.